# My function is not running on click, shows undefined

Tags: javascript, html

My function is not running click, it shows undefined when I check the console of chrome. However, it is defined in the  part.

This is a grade check website, I build different functions to check the grade and I want this big function, to contain all the small functions and this big function will run on click of the submit button.

```js
var SN1 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER1");
        var SN2 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER2");
        var SN3 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER3");
        var SN4 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER4");
        var SN5 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER5");
        var SN6 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER6");
        var SN7 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER7");
        var SN8 = document.getElementById("STANDARDNUMBER8");
        var CRE1 = document.getElementById("CREDITS1");
        var CRE2 = document.getElementById("CREDITS2");
        var CRE3 = document.getElementById("CREDITS3");
        var CRE4 = document.getElementById("CREDITS4");
        var CRE5 = document.getElementById("CREDITS5");
        var CRE6 = document.getElementById("CREDITS6");
        var CRE7 = document.getElementById("CREDITS7");
        var CRE8 = document.getElementById("CREDITS8");
        var UEC1 = document.getElementById("UECHECK1").checked;
        var UEC2 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK2").checked;
        var UEC3 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK3").checked;
        var UEC4 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK4").checked;
        var UEC5 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK5").checked;
        var UEC6 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK6").checked;
        var UEC7 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK7").checked;
        var UEC8 = Document.getElementById("UECHECK8").checked;
        var E1 = document.getElementById("EI1").value = EI1;
        var E2 = document.getElementById("EI2").value = EI2;
        var E3 = document.getElementById("EI3").value = EI3;
        var E4 = document.getElementById("EI4").value = EI4;
        var E5 = document.getElementById("EI5").value = EI5;
        var E6 = document.getElementById("EI6").value = EI6;
        var E7 = document.getElementById("EI1").value = EI7;
        var E8 = document.getElementById("EI1").value = EI8;
        var GRA1 = document.getElementById("GRADE1").value;
        var GRA2 = document.getElementById("GRADE2").value;
        var GRA3 = document.getElementById("GRADE3").value;
        var GRA4 = document.getElementById("GRADE4").value;
        var GRA5 = document.getElementById("GRADE5").value;
        var GRA6 = document.getElementById("GRADE6").value;
        var GRA7 = document.getElementById("GRADE7").value;
        var GRA8 = document.getElementById("GRADE8").value;



        function UECreCheck() {
            if ((UEC1 == true) || (GRA1 == "A") || (GRA1 == "M") || (GRA1 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE1 = CRE1;
            } else if ((UEC1 == false) || (GRA1 == "A") || (GRA1 == "M") || (GRA1 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE1 = 0 ; 
            }
            else{
                var UEAPPCRE1 = 0 ; 
                var CRE1 = 0 ;
                var Missed1 = CRE1;
            }
            if ((UEC2 == true) || (GRA2 == "A") || (GRA2 == "M") || (GRA2 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE2 = CRE2;
            }
                else if ((UEC2 == false) || (GRA2 == "A") || (GRA2 == "M") || (GRA2 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE2 = 0 ; 
            }
            else{
                var UEAPPCRE2 = 0 ; 
                var CRE2 = 0 ;
                var Missed2 = CRE2;
            }
            if ((UEC3 == true) || (GRA3 == "A") || (GRA3 == "M") || (GRA3 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE3 = CRE3;
            } else if ((UEC3 == false) || (GRA3 == "A") || (GRA3 == "M") || (GRA3 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE3 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE3 = 0 ; 
                var CRE3 = 0 ;
                var Missed3 = CRE3;
            }
            if ((UEC4 == true) || (GRA4 == "A") || (GRA4 == "M") || (GRA4 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE4 = CRE4;
            } else if ((UEC4 == false) || (GRA4 == "A") || (GRA4 == "M") || (GRA4 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE4 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE4 = 0 ; 
                var CRE4 = 0 ;
                var Missed4 = CRE4;
            }
            if ((UEC5 == true) || (GRA5 == "A") || (GRA5 == "M") || (GRA5 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE5 = CRE5;
            } else if ((UEC5 == false) || (GRA5 == "A") || (GRA5 == "M") || (GRA5 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE5 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE5 = 0 ; 
                var CRE5 = 0 ;
                var Missed5 = CRE5;
            }
            if ((UEC6 == true) || (GRA6 == "A") || (GRA6 == "M") || (GRA6 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE6 = CRE6;
            } else if ((UEC6 == false) || (GRA6 == "A") || (GRA6 == "M") || (GRA6 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE6 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE6 = 0 ; 
                var CRE6 = 0 ;
                var Missed6 = CRE6;
            }
            if ((UEC7 == true) || (GRA7 == "A") || (GRA7 == "M") || (GRA7 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE7 = CRE7;
            } else if ((UEC7 == false) || (GRA7 == "A") || (GRA7 == "M") || (GRA7 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE7 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE7 = 0 ; 
                var CRE7 = 0 ;
                var Missed7 = CRE7;
            }
            if ((UEC8 == true) || (GRA8 == "A") || (GRA8 == "M") || (GRA8 == "E")) {
                var UEAPPCRE8 = CRE8;
            } else if ((UEC8 == false) || (GRA8 == "A") || (GRA8 == "M") || (GRA8 == "E")) { 
                var UEAPPCRE8 = 0 ; 
            } else{
                var UEAPPCRE8 = 0 ; 
                var CRE8 = 0 ;
                var Missed8 = CRE8;
            }
        }
            function UECheck() {
                var TotalUE = UEAPPCRE1 + UEAPPCRE2 + UEAPPCRE3 + UEAPPCRE4 + UEAPPCRE5 + UEAPPCRE6 + UEAPPCRE7 + UEAPPCRE8 ;
                if(TotalUE >= 14){
                   document.getElementById.("UECheckP").innerHTML = "You have passed the university entrence of this subject.";
                   }
                else if ((TotalUE >= 100)||(TotalUE < 0)){
                    document.getElementById.("UECheckP").innerHTML = "Please check your input of credits.";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById.("UECheckP").innerHTML = "You have not passed the university entrence of this subject.";
                }
            }
            function CreditsGet() {
                var TotalCredits = CRE1 + CRE2 + CRE3 + CRE4 + CRE5 + CRE6 + CRE7 + CRE8 ;
                if (TotalCredits > 0){
                    document.getElementById.("TotalCre").innerHTML = "You have gain" + TotalCredits + "credits in this subject.";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById.("TotalCre").innerHTML = "Please check your input of credits.";
                }
            }
            function MissedCre() {
                var TotalMissed = Missed1 + Missed2 + Missed3 + Missed4 + Missed5 + Missed6 + Missed7 + Missed8 ;
                if (TotalMissed > 0){
                    document.getElementById.("TotalMiss").innerHTML = "You have missed" + TotalMissed + "credits in this subject.";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById.("TotalCre").innerHTML = "Please check your input of credits.";
                }
            }
            function TheBigFunction() {
                UECreCheck();
                UECheck();
                CreditsGet();
                MissedCre();
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HBHS Grades Checking System</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="author" content="Xinyuan Zhai"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="NCEA , Grades , University , University Entrence"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/HBHS-Icon32-32.jpg" type="image/jpg">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><img src="images/Banner%201920-360%20white.jpg" alt="Banner" width=80% id="bannerimg"></div>
        <div id="paragraph">
            <h1 id="instruction">Hi, please enter the result of ONE of your subject in the table.</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="table">
        <table>
            <tr id="table heading">
            <th>Standard Number</th>
            <th>Number of Credits</th>
            <th>AS/US</th>
            <th>UE Approved</th>
            <th>Ext/Int</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="1">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER1" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS1" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS1">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK1" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI1">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI1" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI1" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE1">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade1" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade1" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade1" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade1" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="2">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER2" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS2" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS2">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK2" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI2">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI2" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI2" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE2">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade2" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade2" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade2" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade2" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="3">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER3" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS3" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS3">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK3" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI3">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI3" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI3" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE3">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade3" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade3" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade3" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade3" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="4">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER4" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS4" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS4">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK4" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI4">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI4" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI4" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE4">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade4" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade4" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade4" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade4" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="5">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER5" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS5" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS5">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK5" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI5">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI5" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI5" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE5">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade5" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade5" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade5" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade5" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="6">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER6" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS6" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS6">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK6" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI6">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI6" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI6" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE6">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade6" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade6" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade6" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade6" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="7">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER7" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS7" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS7">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK6" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI7">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI7" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI7" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE7">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade7" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade7" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade7" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade7" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <tr id="8">
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="99999" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="STANDARDNUMBER8" title="5 Degits Standard Number">
                    <input type="submit" id="test1">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="number" id="CREDITS8" min="0" max="40">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="US/AS8">
                    <option value="US">Unit Standard</option>
                    <option value="AS" selected>Achievement Standard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="UECHECK8" value="UE" checked><p>UE Approved</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="EI8">
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI8" id="external" value="External"> External<br>
                    <input type="radio" name = "EI8" id="internal" value="Internal"> Internal
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="GRADE8">
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade8" id="excellent" value="E"> Excellent<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade8" id="merit" value="M"> Merit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade8" id="achieved" value="A"> Achieved<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Grade8" id="not achieved" value="NA"> Not Achieved<br>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="Submit Button">
            <input type="submit" id="The Button" onclick="TheBigFunction()">
        </div>
        <div id="Result">
            <p id="UECheckP"></p>
            <p id="TotalCre"></p>
            <p id="TotalMiss"></p>
        </div>
        
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js">
           
        </script>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

I expected the inner HTML of the `<p>` can change to their grade, shows endorsement and UE credit status, also total credits missed.

[image: The chrome screenshot]

Comment: `it shows undefined` what does? `TheBigFunction` seems to just call 4 functions, none of which you've shown, and nothing you've shown would "show" anything "anywhere"

Comment: ahh, a screenshot of an error ... why didn't you write the error in the question ... anyway, the issue can't be reproduced with the code you've shown in the question .... see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/810oc95u/) does not produce that error

Comment: Is this the full code ? u should type something inside `TheBigFunction` 's code block so when it is called it does what u wanted to do

Comment: I'll bet it's a scope problem, you probably defined the function inside another function. `onclick` can only refer to names in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I pasted my whole file in the question. Thanks for helping! Any comments are welcomed, as I am new to Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add the function inside

```
window.onload = function () {
  // here code
};
```

Comment: I add the function in my js file it's not working... Should this code be put in the js file?

Comment: add this code to js file and add all codes inside this function

Answer (score 0):

So, there are quite a few things you could do to improve the code. I'll do two things here -- first, post some slightly improved code, and then offer some advice about how to improve your own `JavaScript`. Cool?

#### The Updated Code

```
const values = {}; 

function doItAll() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        const UE = document.getElementById(`UECHECK${i}`).checked;
        const GRA = document.getElementById(`GRADE${i}`).value;
        const CRE = document.getElementById(`CREDITS${i}`);
        const grades = ['A', 'M', 'E'];
        if (UE === true || grades.some(GRA)) {
            values[`UEAPPCRE${i}`] = CRE;
        } else if (UE === false || grades.some(GRA)) {
            values[`UEAPPCRE${i}`] = 0;
        } else {
            values[`UEAPPCRE${i}`] = 0;
            values[`CRE${i}`] = 0;
            values[`Missed${i}`] = CRE;
        }
    }
}

function testingItOut() {

    const uECheckP = document.getElementById("UECheckP");
    const totalCre = document.getElementById('TotalCre');
    const totalMiss = document.getElementById('TotalMiss');

    let totalUE = 0;
    let totalCredits = 0;
    let totalMissed = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        totalUE += values[`UEAPPCRE${i}`];
        totalCredits += values[`CRE${i}`];
        totalMissed += values[`Missed${i}`];
    }

    uECheckP.innerHTML = `Passed: ${totalUE >= 14 
        ? 'You have passed the university entrence of this subject.' 
        : (totalUE >= 100 || totalUE < 0) 
        ? 'Please check your input of credits.' 
        : 'You have not passed the university entrence of this subject.'}`;

    totalCre.innerHTML = `Credits: ${totalCredits > 0 
        ? `You have gained ${totalCredits} credits in this subject.`
        : 'Please check your input of credits.'}`;

    totalMiss.innerHTML = `Missed: ${totalMissed > 0
        ? `You have missed ${totalMissed} credits in this subject.`
        : 'Please check your input of credits.'}`;
}

    function TheBigFunction() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            doItAll();
            testingItOut();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The document hasn't finished loading!";
        }
    }
```

So, to start, you had a whole grip of global variables in your original code that used the `var` keyword. I'd suggest researching ES6 syntax (specifically, [`let` and `const`](https://tylermcginnis.com/var-let-const/)), `scope`, and `context`. Try to stay away from `var` declarations.

In the updated code, you'll see I used ES6 template literals to dynamically refer to the `values` object variable, which "houses" properties with values for essentially all of the variables your original code used. Note, too, the use of loops -- you have eight broad element and variable categories, so instead of having to write each one out, I've shown how you can dynamically reference them. I'd also suggest looking a bit more into your logic (specifically, the `doItAll` function).

Typically, `JavaScript` variables are constructed using `camelCase`, so give that a look, too. Following this convention will make your code more readable, especially if you're going to be posting on SO. And, at least within your HTML, note that things like IDs and classes tend to follow the `kebab-case` style. I know, too many styles -- nothing's 100 percent, of course, but most developers and companies tend to stick to these conventions.

There were syntax errors throughout -- you capitalized `document` ~10 times or so, as well as followed several `document.getElementById`s with a period before the ensuing opening parenthesis. Be careful there!

In terms of scope, variables declared within a function aren't accessible outside the function, at least not directly. So, within your `UECreCheck` function, you declared ~24 variables or so and then tried to access their values directly further down in the remaining functions. The values in these cases will be `undefined`, which isn't helpful.

Finally, while not wholly necessary (depending on your use case), I've added a check within `TheBigFunction` -- if your user (or you) calls `TheBigFunction` before the document has loaded, the various DOM-based variable assignments basically won't "see" anything on the page, so you have to make sure you check things are `ready` or after they've `loaded` before you reference the DOM.

To answer your original question, too, try not to use HTML attributes such as `onclick`. Instead, in your HTML file, remove the `onclick` attribute and function invocation, and instead add this to your `functions.js` file:

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('the-button').addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        TheBigFunction();
    });
};
```

I'm down for engaging further on this -- the example here isn't by any means the best, but it shows how you *could* simplify your code, update your syntax, etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I am new to js and I can see from your answer, I still need to learn a lot. There is lots of skills you have used but I never see before. The create of variables is very helpful!

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!